# How to create an Xpath in a tricky section of document (for me) for the purpose of using with Selenium Basic in VBA

Tags: selenium, xpath

OK, so I mentioned Selenium Basic as that is the use of the XPath and I believe Selenium Basic uses Selenium version 2 so maybe it won't be able to understand some/all answers that might require the latest Selenium. But someone might take that into account if necessary.

There are dynamic classes at play here.

**Criteria for selection.**

**1.** Class starting with 'NextToJump__eventWrapper' (the outer one) must be used.

**2.** Class starting with 'NextToJump__venue' must contain text = 'Ballarat'

**3.** Class starting with 'NextToJump__race' (and/or span) must contain text = 'Race 2'

I need to be able to click on the `<a>` tag that contains Points 2 and 3.

The best that I've been able to do (and checked) using ChroPath in Chrome Devtools is...

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'NextToJump__eventWrapper')]//descendant::*[contains(text(),'Ballarat')]
```

But note that there are 2 cases of Point 2 in the HTML but only 1 case that satisfies Points 2 and 3.

Thanks

```html
<div class="NextToJump__eventWrapper--13zZJ">
    <div>
        <div class="NextToJump__raceEvent--bfMON" data-testid="next-to-jump-item">
            <a class="Link__link--9x4YY" href="/racing-betting/greyhound-racing/crayford-am/20200708/race-1-1801951-58544404">
                <div class="NextToJump__iconWrapper--1yG60"></div>
                <div class="NextToJump__eventDetail--CUzdX">
                    <div class="NextToJump__venue--1jwWA">Ballarat</div>
                    <div class="NextToJump__race--3JydR"><span>Race 1</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="NextToJump__countdown--EG8mR"><span class="Countdown__countdown--4vRpD Countdown__imminent--2yc2K">52s</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="NextToJump__raceEvent--bfMON" data-testid="next-to-jump-item">
            <a class="Link__link--9x4YY active" href="/racing-betting/greyhound-racing/rockhampton/20200708/race-4-1799474-58466521" aria-current="page">
                <div class="NextToJump__iconWrapper--1yG60"></div>
                <div class="NextToJump__eventDetail--CUzdX">
                    <div class="NextToJump__venue--1jwWA">Rockhampton</div>
                    <div class="NextToJump__race--3JydR"><span>Race 4</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="NextToJump__countdown--EG8mR"><span class="Countdown__countdown--4vRpD Countdown__imminent--2yc2K">2m 52s</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="NextToJump__raceEvent--bfMON" data-testid="next-to-jump-item">
            <a class="Link__link--9x4YY" href="/racing-betting/greyhound-racing/ballarat/20200708/race-4-1799454-58465201">
                <div class="NextToJump__iconWrapper--1yG60"></div>
                <div class="NextToJump__eventDetail--CUzdX">
                    <div class="NextToJump__venue--1jwWA">Ballarat</div>
                    <div class="NextToJump__race--3JydR"><span>Race 2</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="NextToJump__countdown--EG8mR"><span class="Countdown__countdown--4vRpD Countdown__imminent--2yc2K">5m 52s</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but there are 3 races in your html snippet, and only one (the last one) has a venue `Ballarat` and a race called `Race 2`. If so, your target is the `<a>` tag right above them. Is all the correct?

Comment: Yes indeed sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath expression you need to use to select your target `<a>` tag is long and convoluted, but that's life....
[formatted for ease of reading, but you can use that in one line]

```
//a
[ancestor::div[starts-with(@class,'NextToJump__eventWrapper')]]
[.//div[.="Ballarat"]
[starts-with(@class,'NextToJump__venue-')]
[./following-sibling::div[.="Race 2"]
[starts-with(@class,'NextToJump__race-')]
]
]
```

Edit:
In "plain English":

Find an `<a>` node which meets ALL these conditions (i) has an ancestor (not a parent) node which is a `<div>`, which `<div>` has a `class` attribute with an attribute name which starts with `NextToJump__eventWrapper`; and (ii) it has `<div>`descendant (not just a child) node, which has `Ballarat` as a text node AND which has a `class` attribute with an attribute name which starts with `NextToJump__venue-`, where that `<div>`descendant itself has a following sibling which is a `<div>` which itself has a `Race 2` text node AND  which has a `class` attribute with an attribute name which starts with `NextToJump__race-`...

Yes, the word "plain" doesn't really fit here, but that's the closest I could get. I like xpath, and it's very powerful, but sometimes it's very hard to follow... As an aside, it would have been somewhat less cryptic if xquery was used instead of straight xpath.

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you so much @Jack. When you have time would you be kind enough to explain what is going on here so I and others may learn.